# PL/SQL function return - gettting error ORA-00905 missing keyword

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to compile a function in pl/sql in the 'body' section of a package.  The intention is to return a number value either when successfully updating a table column or return the number associated with the error:

```
FUNCTION chkMissingData RETURN NUMBER
IS
          BEGIN   
                UPDATE ERRORS
                SET ERRORDESC = 
                CASE 
                WHEN ERRVAL IS NULL THEN 'No data' 
                ELSE 'OK' 
                RETURN 0;     -- ORA-00905 missing keyword

          EXCEPTION
              WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
              dbms_output.put_line('INSERT: Constraint violated ' || ERR_NUM || ', Msg:' || ERR_MSG);   
              RETURN ERR_NUM;

              WHEN OTHERS THEN
              dbms_output.put_line('Error ' || ERR_NUM || ', Msg:' || ERR_MSG);   
              RETURN ERR_NUM;

  END chkMissingData;
```

I've checked other answers to a similar issue but I don't see what I'm missing syntactically.

Answer (score 1):

OK I forgot to place an 'end;' after the CASE statement!

Answer (score 1):

You should use an IDE that includes an automatic formatter, such as SQL Developer. Then you can format and identify common syntax issues like that, before loading the example into StackOverflow.

You can also use livesql.oracle.com to test out your code, make sure it at least compiles, before posting here.

SQL Developer and LiveSQL are entirely free.

Comment: All that is good, but in this case it seems the OP knew exactly where something was missing; he didn't know **what** was missing. SQL Developer will not tell you *that*! {:-)

Comment: In PL/SQL Developer, the formatter puts everything from `update errors` to `else 'OK' return 0;` on one line, which I think at least gives a clue about the missing semicolon. Plus the OP's formatting is just wrong :(

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, the corrected snippet is below..

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
  FUNCTION chkMissingData
    RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN
    UPDATE ERRORS
    SET ERRORDESC =
      CASE
        WHEN ERRVAL IS NULL
        THEN 'No data'
        ELSE 'OK'
      END;
    RETURN 0; -- ORA-00905 missing keyword
  EXCEPTION
  WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('INSERT: Constraint violated ' || ERR_NUM || ', Msg:' || ERR_MSG);
    RETURN ERR_NUM;
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('Error ' || ERR_NUM || ', Msg:' || ERR_MSG);
    RETURN ERR_NUM;
  END chkMissingData;
```

Answer (score 0):

err_num and err_msg are not declared variables.
I think you mean SQLCODE and SQLERRM

(And I'm guessing that ERRVAL is a column of your table ERRORS)